# Foundation 6 huge new project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I recently started a project with Zurb Foundation 6 (been using the foundation 5 for years). I was surprised at the resulting empty project size (45Mb) while the project I've been working on for months (Foundation 5 w/ compass) was barely 10Mb.

The node_modules folder is 43Mb alone... I tried both the git installation method and the CLI methods of installation with similar results (http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html).

With all this my questions are :

- Am I doing something wrong or Foundation 6 really has 40Mb of npm dependencies ?
- Is it time to switch to Bootstraps or just go back to Foundation 5 ?
- Do I worry too much and should just go ahead with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some things to consider:

1. Foundation's size is totally up to you. you can download a custom css-html package with only the elements' you need. try this link [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/#customizeFoundation).
2. using the sass version, the `node_modules` directory shouldn't be used on production enviroment. if you're using git, make sure you're using a `.gitignore` file and including the node directories. here's my .gitignore file for reference:

   ```
   .DS_Store
   *.log
   node_modules/
   ...
   ```
3. regarding which framework to use - that's totally up to you. Twitter's Bootstrap or Zurb's Foundation are high end frameworks and are aimed to speed up your development proccess.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks I didnt know node_modules wasn't needed on prod. This makes much more sense!